# transform scale causes the image to fall out of the body

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transforms

This is my page with many images:
[image]
and When I click on an image; that scales up (`transform: scale(3)`)

Here is my code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
.gallery {
    padding: 1vw 2vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.gallery img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 25vh;
    width: auto;
    margin: 1vw 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border: 5px solid white;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.gallery img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    z-index: 1;
    border-width: 3.33px;
}
.gallery img:focus {
    transform: scale(3);
    z-index: 2;
    border-width: 1.67px;
}
```

the problem is here:
[image]

as you see, I use flexbox and I don't know how can I set a different `transform-origin` for edge images.
can you help me?

Comment: share your html too

Comment: @TemaniAfif `<div class="gallery"><img src="gallery/Image_1.jpg" tabindex="-1"><img src="gallery/Image_2.jpg" tabindex="-1"><!-- other images --><img src="gallery/Image_36.jpg" tabindex="-1"></div>`